# How to initialize a variable with a string then compare an input to it in C?

Tags: c

I tried this and it didn't work

```
char passEntry[10], password[] = "abc";
printf ("Enter password");
scanf ("%s", passEntry);

if passEntry==password
{
     printf ("Access Granted");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like C.

Comment: Look at `string.h`, in particular, `strcmp`.